# Is there a way find what are all the tables & records are updated in last 30mins in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-tasklet

I am debugging a spring batch application that uses Oracle. I am seeing lot of tables getting modified by the spring batch Job. And also , it is very difficult to go through the code base to understand what are all the tables got modified.

Is there an easy way to know what are all the tables & records got modified by the spring batch job?

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more details here.  What is this "job?"

Comment: spring batch  job that updates the oracle database

Comment: If you can identify the Oracle session before it does its work, you can enable tracing of that session.  You'll see all the SQL statements that it issues which might or might not be an overwhelming amount of information compared to just reading/ searching/ debugging the code.  If all your tables happen to be built with `rowdependencies`, you could use `scn_to_timestamp( row_scn )` on each table to see the rows modified in the last 30 minutes but that will be slow if you have any sort of data volume.  If they're not built with `rowdependencies`, you'd get false positives.

Comment: how do I find the Oracle session for the spring batch application?